# Queue runs successfully! Exits instead of continue, after Break

Tags: python, queue

I am using this script to resolve thousands of domains. It runs successfully, and ends when the queue is empty. I am trying to it to break out of the loop and continue the script by printing.

How do I get this code to break out of the loop, ans print, when the queue is empty?

```
q = queue.Queue()
for name in names:
    q.put(name)

def async_dns():
    s = adns.init()

    while True:
        try:
            dname = q.get(False)
            q.task_done()
        except queue.Empty:
            return 
        response = s.synchronous(dname,adns.rr.NS)[0]
        if response == 0:
            dot_net.append("Y")
            print(dname + ", is Y")
        elif response == 300 or response == 30 or response == 60:
            dot_net.append("N")
            print(dname + ", is N")


threads = []
for i in range(20):
    t = threading.Thread(target=async_dns)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()


  print("Done !!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply move the code that does the dns lookup and prints the result into the body of the `try/except` block:

```
def async_dns():
    s = adns.init()

    while True:
        try:
            dname = q.get(False)

            response = s.synchronous(dname,adns.rr.NS)[0]
            if response == 0:
                dot_net.append("Y")
                print(dname + ", is Y")
            elif response == 300 or response == 30 or response == 60:
                dot_net.append("N")
                print(dname + ", is N")

            q.task_done()
        except queue.Empty:
            return
```

Now when the queue is empty a `queue.Empty` will be raised and the exception handler will simply exit the thread function, otherwise it will print out the dns values.